# react submit по нажатию на кнопку enter mui

Tags: reactjs, mui

У меня есть конопка

```
<StyledApplyButton
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  endIcon={<FilterListIcon />}
  onClick={handleSubmit}
  size="small"
>
  {intl.get('APPLY')}
</StyledApplyButton>
```

по клику на эту кнопку отправляется гет запрос, как сделать так чтобы по нажатию на enter срабатывала функцию сабмит handleSubmit, нужно отметить, что у меня нет какой-нибудь формы, просто натыканы поля, дропдауны и календари, я пробовал

```
onkeypress={handleKeyPress(event)}

function handleKeyPress(e){
 var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (key === 13){ // Клавиша Enter
     doSomething();
  }
}
```

не работает(